# How to modify the contents of a range in MATCH()?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am performing a `trim + clean + uppercase` in order to match IDs more easily:

```
=IFNA(MATCH(UPPER(TRIM(CLEAN(A1))), datos!B2:datos!B999, 0), -1)+1
```

This returns the row number, or a 0 and it works just fine.

However, I'm currently referencing the B column, a modified column of ID that passes through a `=UPPER(TRIM(CLEAN(A1)))` instead of the A column with the IDs at their original state.

How can I apply the same process (trim, clean and upper) to both the hay and the needle in a way that eliminates the need of this second column with modified IDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following formula:

```
{=MATCH(TRIM(CLEAN(D2)),TRIM(CLEAN(A2:A5)),0)}
```

This is an array formula, so you will need to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Note that there is no need for `UPPER` since `MATCH` is case insensitive